# regarding gst_element_release_request_pad

Tags: gstreamer

I am having Gstreamer element which has request pad as sink pads. From application, I am requesting pad and linking as follows:

```
    GstPadTemplate *sink_pad_template = gst_element_class_get_pad_template (GST_ELEMENT_GET_CLASS (mElement), "sink_%d");
    GstPad *pad = gst_element_request_pad (mElement, sink_pad_template, NULL, NULL);
    gst_pad_link(gst_element_get_static_pad (mQueue, "src"), pad);
```

Successfully pads are linked, but while releasing request pads gst_element_release_request_pad not returning.
Tried block the previous element's src pad (in pipeline), unlink and then release_request_pad but gst_element_release_request_pad not returning. Please let me know what are the right steps while releasing the request pads?

```
    gst_pad_set_blocked(m_queueSrcPad, true);
    gst_pad_unlink(m_queueSrcPad, pad);
    gst_element_release_request_pad(m_Element, pad);
```

Tried setting source pad as blocked before calling above functions, still this did not help

```
    gst_pad_set_blocked(SrcPad, true); // first element in pipeline
```

Comment: First always check return codes. 2nd does linking always work? 3rd when are you unlinking and releasing the pads - while playing or when the pipeline is READY or NULL? Is the elements that you request pads from your own or an element that comes with gstreamer. If it is your own, check that you implemented the request pad handling correctly.

Comment: 3rd when are you unlinking and releasing the pads: Pipeline is in playing state and basically blocking the previous element source pad and then unlinking and releasing the pads. After this set the element state to NULL and pipeline state to NULL.